# How to create folder in "root directory" with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, http

I made a request to api via ""http"". A list is returned. This list contains the names of the files I want to create. Now I want to use these names when creating files automatically with Flutter. What path should I follow?

Comment: see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Directory-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a directory for the app to store files that only it can access. As a bonus the app doesn't need any additional permissions.

```
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

See [Read and write files](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files) for details.